# function to sum range gives: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, range, iterable

I'm trying to write a function where the user gives the start and end of a range and the output is that range summed. This is my best try:

```
def sum_range (start, end):
    output = 0
    userange = range(start, end)
    for i in userange :
        sum(i, output)

    return output
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Try replacing `sum(i,output)` with `output += i`. It will add `i` to the current value of `ouput`

Comment: Tip: virtually no function in Python accepts an output argument. Results are always *returned*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do :

```
def sum_range(start, end):
    return sum(range(start, end))
```

example :

```
>>> def sum_range(start, end):
...     return sum(range(start, end))
... 
>>> sum_range(10,14)
46
```

Comment: Of course, once you boil it down like that… what's the point of `sum_range()` when you can write `sum(range())`…?

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't need to build a `range` object. Simply take the sum of an arithmetic progression:

```
def sum_range(start, end):
    return (end - start) * (start + end - 1) // 2


print(sum_range(4, 30))
# 429.0
assert sum_range(4, 30) == sum(range(4, 30))
```

Comment: This presupposes that `start <= end`, which `range` handles implicitly.

Comment: the only thing that's different is the datatype of the result returned (`float` vs `int`)

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I added `2.` to handle integer division in Python 2. Nothing to it

Comment: @chepner True. I seem to have assumed that from the OP since they're not passing a stride parameter

Comment: @StefanPochmann I don't see how your point has to do with integer division. Rewriting the same expression as `((start + end - 1)/2) * (end - start)` will lead to problems only in Python 2.

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised that `sum` isn't optimized to recognize when it gets a `range` object to compute the sum directly, instead of iterating.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I think the point is, one of `(end - start)` and `(start + end - 1)` is guaranteed to be even, so since the product is computed first, there's no problem with simply dividing by 2.

Comment: @chepner Right. It's not immediately obvious for someone glancing through  tho.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye That's what comments are for :)

Answer (score 1):

You either need:

```
def sum_range(start, end):
    output = 0
    userange = range(start, end)
    for i in userange:
        output += i

    return output
```

or

```
def sum_range(start, end):
    return sum(range(start, end))
```

Comment: The first option ends up just returning the value given for start. Not sure what that's about.

Comment: @JennaMareeFae Are you sure you typed it correctly? Sounds like you put the `return` statement in the body of the `for` loop.

Comment: Yup, you're totally right I did. I seriously cannot wait to be less noobish at this. Thanks for you help!